# Python dynamically access features of class in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to list the methods in a class and the function arguments. This is more or less a way for me to communicate with the user upfront 1) what the methods are and 2) their arguments they take. In front of each method, I just copy the arguments and past them as a comment on the line above. I then call this in the class constructor

```
import inspect

# List the methods
for method_name, other_stuff in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
    if method_name != '__init__':
        print('  ' + method_name + '(' + inspect.getcomments(self.save).replace('#','').rstrip() + ')')
```

The code above works as expected but the problem is the argument to `getcomments` which is currently `self.save`. Instead, I would like to use the `for loop` argument `method_name` but I do not know how to do this correctly (or if it is possible).

I'm actually interested in this answer beyond my application. In Matlab, there is the ability to use cells to dynamically access structure fields, which is basically what I'm trying to do here I believe. There was also the old `eval()` (frowned upon) approach. I only give these examples to try an elaborate on what I'm specifically trying to do if it isn't clear in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? The builtin for getting an attribute from a class by name, is getattr.

```
import inspect

class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self,x):
        '''x'''
        return x+1
    def list_methods(self):
        ''''''
        for method_name, other_stuff in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
            if method_name != '__init__':
                print(f'  {method_name}({getattr(self,method_name).__doc__})')
t = Thing()
t.list_methods()
```

You could also use the inspect.getargspec(func) to find the arguments used without needing to create doc strings. You could also use the functions annotations instead of the .**doc** string.

Comment: OK....so it looks like the key is `getattr(self,method_name)`. I tested that in my original script and it works.  I'll have to do some more reading on that, but it seems like this might be what I was looking for. BTW I liked your alternative approach to printing the comments. I didn't know about `__doc__` .  I did see the `inspect.getargspec(func)` approach, but the output isn't necessarily "user friendly", hence why I just used comments

Comment: Maybe to improve your answer to help others, just highlight in the beginning of your answer that "the key is `getattr(self,method_name)`"

Comment: The getattr, hasattr, and setattr are very useful built-in functions to learn. Yes, triple quotes in a function automatically add to a functions __doc__ attribute. You can also use the annotations of the function instead.